# How do I stop img:hover from affecting css from 800px and up?

Tags: html, css, hover

I added the image hover to the media query for when the screen size gets to 600px and lower, but now it's affecting all screen sizes. I tried using `Display: none` to stop it, but it's not working. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ In order to help you SO contributors will need to see some code. Please visit this link for advice on how to provide a Minimal Reproducible Example >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works

```
@media screen and (max-width:600px){

img:hover{
//do somting
}
}
```

Comment: Is that real HTML?

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks, I'll have to try it.